# Question same but with different answer and posted at different time

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Suppose that person "A" posted the question in the SO and that was answered by person "B" say 6 months ago. Now, if person "C" posts the new question which is close to "A"(may or may not be without knowledge of previous one) and person "D" answers the question (without knowledge of previous one). Person C is convinced with the answer of person D. Now if person "E" comes and says it is a duplicate and should be closed. But person "C" says I was not aware of the previous question (may be true or not) and I am not convinced with the answer of person "B". Remember the time lag here. My question here is what is the policy of SO with same question but different answer (posted with the time lag and which person D who answers the duplicate question is not aware of previous question before answering).

Comment: Just let it be, nothing wrong with duplicates. It's like two roads that reach the same destination. :)

Comment: I like how this question is talking about C posting a duplicate of A's question, but the answers to this question are (mainly) talking about D posting a duplicate of B's answer :)

Comment: @ doubleDown: which is not; I wish the answers come from the moderators (SO or meta) who ultimately decides what has to be done. This is serious since you can solve the same question in different ways.Let's wait and see what are their opinions.

Answer (score 6):

The policy is to give the benefit of the doubt to person D. Without proof content was plagiarised we assume that person D just happened to also know the answer (which is the most likely event).

The question is closed as a duplicate (if 5 people agree it is a duplicate) and the system works!

Comment: I know how the system works; but my question is if it doesn't have duplicate answers which is not hard enough (for those who votes to close) to decide whether it is not plagiarised (to borrow your word).

Comment: @user227710 Duplicate doesn't suggest plagiarism at all. It just suggests that it is duplicate. AFAIK, the new question and it's answer will continue to exist (if they have upvotes) and just have a link to the original question and it's answer. win-win. :)

Comment: @Anders: Yeah, but wouldn't it be better if we have a policy with duplicate questions but not duplicate answers

Answer (score 1):

- If answer by D looks like an exact copy-paste from B, with the same words, sentences, typos et cetera, without a link to original, you can flag for moderator's attention.
- If it's worded differently, probably D simply knew right answer and nothing wrong happened.
- If D copy-pasted answer, but with link to clearly indicate original source, it is possible and probable D was thinking it's similar, but not duplicate question, and did his best to make answer available within content license limits. Again, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: thanks for your answer